# javascript to print all tables and individual tables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am retrieving values from a database and displaying it a table using php. Each table is stored inside a div tag.

```
<div id="print">
table content 1
</div>

<div id="print">
table content 2
</div> ..................
```

Can some one please suggest a javascript where i can get a separate link/ button that will print all the tables and a link on all table to print each individual table. I used several javascripts and jquery plug ins but couldn't get my job done.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips:

1. IDs should be unique across the document. Use classes do identify your tables.
2. Set proper CSS rules with @media=print so only your tables get printed.
3. The "Print all tables" button is straightforward: just send the whole document to printer.
4. The "Print this table" button must do this:

   1. Identify the table (put the button inside the table or in a common container)
   2. Set a CSS class to all other tables so they won't print
   3. Send the whole document to printer
   4. Set the original CSS classes back

If you are unsure about any of the steps feel free to ask.

### Update: identify table

Just one of the many possibilities:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function printThisTable(button){
    var $table = $(button).closest("div").find("table");

    alert("Table found: " + $table.text());
}
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <table><tr><td>I'm table A</td></tr></table>
    <p><input type="button" onclick="printThisTable(this)" value="Print this table"></p>
</div>

<div>
    <table><tr><td>I'm table B</td></tr></table>
    <p><input type="button" onclick="printThisTable(this)" value="Print this table"></p>
</div>

<div>
    <table><tr><td>I'm table C</td></tr></table>
    <p><input type="button" onclick="printThisTable(this)" value="Print this table"></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didnt understand 4.2 and 4.4 .. Can you explain it a bit more please??

Comment: 4.4 just refers to using the addClass() and removeClass() method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have separate ids for each div. Like print1, print2, etc. Then you can get or set the values using Document.getElementById("print1").innerHTML

Here's some quick functions that could help:

```
function getContents(id) {
  var contents = Document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
  return contents;
}

function setContents(id, value) {
  Document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
}
```

Now you can use a loop to call either/both of those functions as appropriate. You could also modify the getContents() function to print to whereever you want the output sent.